# jQuery Mobile TypeError when closing a dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I first noticed this when working on a PhoneGap project, but I can replicate it on the jQuery mobile demo site too.

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/pages-dialog/

When I open a dialog, and then close it using the close button in the top corner, I get this error in my console (using Safari 7.0.1):

```
[Error] TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '("string"==typeof g?f[g]:g).apply')
```

This exact same error occurs using a dialog in my personal project, implemented like so:

```
<a href="#help" data-dialog="true" data-transition="none">Help</a>

<div data-role="page" data-dialog="true" id="help">
    <div data-role="header"></div>
    <p>Help Information Here</p>
</div>
```

The dialog closes as you would expect it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're hitting a known issue in jQuery Mobile 1.4:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/6968

This is now fixed in jQuery Mobile 1.4.1.